# What happens when solution containing two or more cations are electrolysed at an excess potential?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, kinetics, electrolysis

> $\pu{250 mL}$ of a waste solution obtained from the workshop of a goldsmith contains $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{AgNO3}$ and $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{AuCl}$. The solution was electrolyzed at $\pu{2 V}$ by passing a current of $\pu{1 A}$ for 15 minutes. The metal/metals electrodeposited will be:
>
> (1) only silver
> (2) only gold
> (3) silver and gold in equal mass proportion
> (4) silver and gold in proportion to their atomic weights

I came across this question whose answer was given as (4). But I doubt the answer. I think that the molar ratio should depend on the ionic mobilities of the cations and shouldn't equal 1.

Am I thinking right? A qualitative answer explaining this would be appreciated.

Comment: It is highly inprobable you could make 0.1 M [AuCl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold(I)_chloride). And [AuCl3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold(III)_chloride) forms with water $\ce{[AuCl3(OH)]-}$ anion. The task seems to me as made up, being detached from reality.

Comment: This problem is impossible for two reasons. First $\ce{AuCl}$ cannot form $\pu{0.1 M}$ solutions, as it is decomposed in water without $\ce{HCl}$ . And second $\ce{Ag+}$ will react with chlorine compounds like $\ce{AuCl}$ to produce silver chloride $\ce{AgCl}$ which is insoluble in water.

Comment: Choice 4 is roughly correct, instead of atomic weights, they should write equivalent weights.

Comment: @Maurice I thought of that also. But consider this as a hypothetical question or, replace AuCl with any other compound that doesn't react and is stable under the conditions

Comment: @Govind. I like impossible questions, like : How long will it take for a sparrow to fly up to the Sun ? This question can be solved, by dividing the distance by the speed.